# Malloc allocating same address in memory?

Tags: c, malloc

I found similar questions to mine, but I still can't figure out why my code is acting the way it is.

I have a struct called "rectangle", and here is the code that I am trying to run:

```
Rectangle *newRect = (Rectangle *)malloc(sizeof(Rectangle));
Rectangle *newRect2 = (Rectangle *)malloc(sizeof(Rectangle));
printf("rect1: %p rect2: %p",newRect,newRect2);
```

It outputs the same address for both of them, what am I doing wrong?

Thanks!

Comment: You do not need the cast

Comment: You are either a) not running that exact code you posted or b) freeing `newRect` before the second call to `malloc`.

Comment: Please show us an SSCCE that exhibits this behaviour: http://sscce.org/

Comment: @EdHeal it's good practice, it's required in C++, and it's often a warning in C.

Comment: @o11c But question tagged in `C`.I don't think it's good.[You can check yourself](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/605845/do-i-cast-the-result-of-malloc)

Comment: @o11c - You use new in C++ not malloc. C does not require the cast nor is it good practice

Comment: @o11c no, it is not good practice. neither is a C-typecast in C++ good practice.

Comment: can you check how mush is sizeof(Rectangle)

Comment: @EdHeal you most certainly do not use `new` just because it's C++; the semantics are not compatible. And it's quite important for a lot of code to be compatible with C++ as well as C. If anything, you would use a macro that's ifdef'ed to use `static_cast<T*>(p)` in C++ and `(T *)p` (glibc has a private one).

Comment: sizeof(Rectangle) = 48

Comment: @o11c - You do as C++ is a different beast to C. It also avoids a whole lot of problems with programmers having to decide if they should use free/delete. As to using macors in C++ that is another can of worms than is best avoided

Comment: @GregBrinker - What is the output?

Comment: @EdHeal Rules about writing C++ from scratch do not apply to existing C legacy codebases. During a conversion , `new` and `delete` are exceptionally rare, and when they do exist they are wrapped in some sort of (non-smart) pointer class. And when used *carefully*, macros are capable of much more obviousness and flexibility than other code. I'm just about to rewrite some code that uses a template and lambdas to use a macro instead, in fact.

Comment: have you tried to change the pointer to `int*` or so? something like https://ideone.com/TKCYjQ

Comment: it outputs Root rect ptr: 0x7f828ad00000
New rect ptr: 0x7f828ad00000

Comment: As @NPE already has requested, please post a minimal but complete code example that produces your output, and also please tell us the specification of your platform, OS, compiler etc.

Comment: Not shown earlier code corrupted memory.

Answer (score 2):

You probably don't compile with all warnings on, and forgot to include `stdlib.h`. `malloc` is then by some compilers interpreted to return `int` instead of `void*`. On a 64 bit architecture this looses significant information and thus at the end you see the same value in your print.

**Don't cast the return of `malloc`.**

Comment: I have incuded stdlib.h. I also removed the cast, same things are happening

Comment: @Cicada, no it *is* not dictated by the standard, it was. Using a function without having seen a definition is a constraint violation in modern C.